# Sending facebook user-to-user private message without a dialog from Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat, facebook-messenger

I am interested in sending a private message from a Facebook user to another, through my app. I would like to use my Android app to do it. The thing is, my app interacts with the user by voice.

One option is to use the Send Message Dialog, but in this case, the user would have to physically press the send button, but my app should send it when the user says the word "Send", without touching the screen. Does anyone know how to control the new dialog by voice? I highly doubt that is possible.

Another option would be to use Facebook Chat API, but it will soon be shut down, so I don't really want to use it now.

Please let me know of any other way to get around it, if you know. Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to send message with  dialog using new SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way of doing what you're looking for. Facebook does not allow the creation of private messages via the API. The Chat API was the only way to do this, and as you say - it's being deprecated.